# Calculate vertical angle in FOV in Visibility Analysis

Tags: qgis, visibility

I use the Visibility Analysis plugin in QGIS quite regularly to calculate Depth Below Horizon for  a wind turbine to identify how much of the turbine is visible across the DEM as part of LVIA studies. I would like to be able to calculate how much of a visual receptor's vertical field of view is affected by the turbine - is this possible? I know there are ways to cut-off the analysis using upper and lower angle masks but that is not what I am after.

I have considered using a proximity raster and trigonometry with the raster calculator to calculate the angle. However, I think this would only work on a completely flat DEM (i.e. the visual receptor on the DEM is at the same elevation as the base of the turbine).